# Survival Statistics Independence

Tags: survival, independence, censoring

If we observe follow-up times $T_i = \min(X_i,C_i)$ and right censoring indicators $δ_i = I(X_i \le C_i)$ under noninformative censoring. Is $X_i$ independent of $δ_i$?

Please explain why!